# svg element covers links

Tags: css, svg

I have a big svg element on the top of the website. It is set "absolute" and there are links on top of invisible parts of the svg. These links are somehow not active and I can't make it work with "z-index". As soon as they are out of reach of the svg, they are active as usual. Is there another parameter apart from "z-index" I can use to prevent this happening?

```
<html>
<defs> 
    <symbol id="svg1">
            <path id="headcurve1" d="M739.009,0H0.078L0,61.997c266.167-18.812,518.333,4.271,739.134,62.977L739.009,0z">
     </symbol>  
       <filter id="f5" width="120%" height="120%">
         <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1.5"result="out1"/>
            <feOffset in="out1" dx=".1" dy=".1" result="out2" />
          <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="out2" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>
       </filter>
 </defs>

    <div id="sidemenu">
       <h2>Aktuelles</h2>
        <br>
        <a>several links</a>
        <a>several links</a>
        <a>several links</a>
    </div>

</html>
```

css:

```
#headcurve1 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 2;
}

#sidemenu {
width: 250px;
float: right;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 20px;
z-index: 20;
{
```

Comment: why you can't use z-index? And can you show your code?

Comment: please give us more information, so we can help you, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's quiet difficult without seeing the code, but I can imagine the error. What happen if you use that image as a background image (inside a div for instance) and then you just put the links inside that component?

Comment: pointer-events: none; perhaps

Comment: @RobertLongson knows what's up

Comment: I added the code with the pieces which are relevant. Does it make sense?